# Difference between MergeOption.NoTracking, ObjectContext.Detach, SetChangeTracker(Null)

Tags: entity-framework

Hi
If anyone could please elaborate the difference between the three, i am new to EF and sometimes MergeOption.NoTracking happens to work whereas sometimes ObjectContext.Detach, but i never get the gist of it.
I would like to know Which situations should i use them.  Also, if there is an object graph attached to some entity (either by firing the Include function or by calling EntityReference.Load()) What should be called if
1.) i don't want other objects attached to the entity
2.) i want all objects referenced by the entity

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards
Hiren

Answer (score 2):

`MergeOption.NoTracking` is used to improver performance for loading entities which will not be modified. Entity is in this case is not tracked by the context but it is still attached and **lazy loading works**.

`ObjectContext.Detach` completely removes entity from object context scope so the entity is not tracked and **lazy loading doesn't work**.

`IEntityWithChangeTracker.SetChangeTracker` is imho more like infrastructure for `EntityObject`. It is heavily used inside EF when entities are materialized and attached to the context.